# Save image from s3

Tags: typescript, image, parsing, amazon-s3

Trying to save a file from s3, but it is saved in some encrypted form,

long file of `gGAIIAAAAAMMQQAAAAAAYhgACAAAAwDAEEAAvvJCQUJ04dS6ty0iWazfuyPfG7bQuAwCAZLNL6wIAICU9ehQir2OndeTYKR31Pq1Tp8/Kx+eq....`
I want to save it in a way I can view, could be two things:

1. the format I'm saving it in the bucket changes the format
2. The way I parse it when I download

This is how I upload it to s3

```
async (fileName: string, fileContent: Buffer, bucketName: string) => {
try {
    const s3 = new AWS.S3(AWSConf);

    const params = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: fileName,
        Body: fileContent,
    };

    await s3.putObject(params).promise();

} catch (err) {
    console.error('Error:', err);
}
```

This is how I'm getting it:

```
        const params = { Bucket: bucketName, Key: key, ResponseContentType: "image/png" };
    const { Body } = await s3.getObject(params).promise();
    if (!Body) {
        throw new Error('No data found for the S3 object.');
    }
    const directoryPath = path.dirname(localFilePath);

    fs.mkdirSync(directoryPath, { recursive: true });
    fs.writeFileSync(localFilePath, Body.toString('base64'));
    console.log(`Downloaded ${path.basename(key)}`);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is that AWS library that you are using but it seems that you are saving the body (stream? buffer?) as base64, you needs to save it as-is, without encoding.